# Passing a request's ID to outgoing WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, cookies, channelfactory, wcfserviceclient

I have to pass the request ID to it's outgoing WCF service call and take the request ID inside the WCF operation. How can i achieve this.?

To an outgoing Httprequest, I use the CookieContainer and store the ID in a new Cookie and take the ID from the HttpRequest.Cookies from the other application.

Likewise I need to assign value from a web request and call a WCF service operation. And Inside the WCF operation i need to take the assigned value.

How this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders 
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders
```

within a method or custom class deriving *IClientMessageInspector/IDispatchMessageInspecto*r for client and service respectively.